# Create button partially behind background image

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to create a button that partially behind a background image.  Meaning, basically just the left edge of the button is covered.  The problem I'm running into, is that because it's a background image, the only way I'm able to get the button behind it is to set the button's z-index lower than the layer with the background image, which in turn, makes the button unclickable.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the button behind an adjacent element. You can't hide it behind just the "background image" because the image is applied to the element itself, so you have to hide it behind the element. The visible part of the button is still clickable.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  background: url('http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg') top left no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: so if the image was say a shape, and not a perfect square, there's no way to do it since the element doesn't really care about the shape of the image?

Comment: @VonKieffer this is where an example of your code would be helpful. But forget the image - if the button is fully behind the element, no you can't click on it. But if you can make part of the button not be behind the element, then you can click on the part that isn't behind the element.